# .zip file download with reactjs has corrupted content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, zip

My backend (in nodejs) uses a webservice that allows to download a file from a distant server. It has to "return" the download towards my reactJS webapp in the frontend.

The download is functionnal when testing the service with the swagger. Thus, my backend returns a string with the raw data, which I re-interpet to download.

My frontend treatment is as such :

```js
downloadFile(){
    let path = this.props.result.link;
    let name = this.props.result.fileName;

    downloader.downloadAFile(path,name).then( response => {
      if (response){
        if (response.success == true) {
          let bytes = this.data64ToArrayBuffer(response.data);   
          var file = new File([bytes],this.props.result.fileName+".zip",{type: "application/zip"});
          fileSaver.saveAs(file);

        } else {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.data == "Fichier introuvable."){
            window.alert(response.data);
          }
        }
      }
    }).catch(function (error){
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

dataToArrayBuffer = (data) => {
    var binaryString = data;
    console.log(binaryString);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
       var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
       bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
 }
```

For a file named "test.txt", containing "test" as text, at the "/PATH/TO/FOLDER" path, the API should propose a zip file to download, names "test.txt.zip", with inside, all the folders trees /PATH/TO/FOLDER, and in the final folder, the mentionned file.

My download in the frontend is effective in some way since it downloads a zip with the right name, the right size, and the right folder tree inside.
However, the test.txt file in the final folder of the path seems to be corrupted, for when I try to open it in 7zip, I have the following error : CRC failed : test.txt .

I suspect it is a problem with how I handle the raw data. I'll take any hints and leads, since I am effectively blocked.

Comment: Gets are chunked - you are not getting the entire file contents, check this: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

Comment: Ah, I see. I have to check how Axios implements that since I use this package. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I usually skip using packages like that, because it makes it a living hell to debug even simple things :D

Comment: I followed the example in node documentation to reconstitute all the chunks. Unfortunately, the result is the same. I'll follow any other lead, and would be glad if anyone had another idea, since I don't see where this could come from.

Comment: But wait, you just rename the file as zip and that's it? The bytes are not zip bytes - they are just the text file bytes. You are just overwriting the type. Check this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip. Just making the file type zip and overriding the mime type is not enough to create a zip file :)

Comment: The first API returns a zip file, so I thought the bytes are already those of a zip, and I just had restitute them. But you might be on to something with this, I will try it out, thanks.